# How to pass data from an external script to a Vue 3 component

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, payment-gateway

I've posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77944960/vue-3-uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined) about the same problem, only now I intend to solve it from another angle.

In my index.html file, I have a script with a function that, when invoked, must pass data to a Vue component.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + Vue</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
    <script>
      function culqi() {
        if (Culqi.token) {
          const token = Culqi.token.id;
          console.log("Token: ", token);
          // pass token to component
        } else if (Culqi.order) {
          const order = Culqi.order;
          console.log("Order: ", order);
          // pass order to component
        } else {
          console.log("Error : ", Culqi.error);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to place the function inside the component but I cannot invoke it and it appears as undefined. You can see my other question to see what I mean.

In my tests, when I placed the function directly in the index.html file, it could be called without problems. So now I intend to use it from there, but I need it to pass data to my component.

How do I do it?

Comment: why don't you `return` whatever you want to "pass", and call the function as required?

Comment: Because it is also invoked from outside the Vue component. Apparently, my Vue3 app is not aware that this function exists. I would like to change the value of a ref inside my component.

Comment: but `function culqi` is global? what does "awareness" have to do with it ... call the function when you need to - as it stands, you never call the function, so it's a pointless piece of code

Comment: I´m trying to implement a payment gateway. When you submit the card information, the payment gateway returns a token to the culqi function directly and the console.log works fine. But it is not me or my Vue app invoking the culqi function. Is an external script. it is on the step 5 of their documentation (in spanish) https://docs.culqi.com/es/documentacion/checkout/v4/culqi-checkout/

Comment: Oh, so it's a payment gateway. You should've said so. Doesn't make a bit of difference to how code works

Comment: Not helping. Maybe you have a real answer to my question.

Comment: Seems it's a difficult thing you're trying to get someone to do for you. Have you attempted anything at all?

Comment: Ahh, I just read your other question - I think I know why culqui wasn't global there - please see my comment on your older question

Comment: I workaround this problem with a solution for my other question thanks to Jaromanda X